# Discretizing functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, discrete-mathematics, resampling

I have the following function and set of values:

```
z(t):   {R → [-2,3] | z(t) = sin(0.5×π×t) + cos(2×π×t) + 1

t = [-1 : 0.001 : 1]
```

I need to determine `z(n×Ts) = z(n)`, using the sample period `Ts=0.01`, therefore discretizing the fucnction.

I tried using d2d, but for what I've understood can only be applied to zpk functions.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Its a matlab question which is related to a project. I didn't just post my homework, I tried using d2d and failed, as I've tried other methods.

Comment: Care to show us what you have cooked up so far? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a zero order hold approximation of your signal, this can be done by following code:

```
Ts = 0.01;
t = -1:0.001:1;
n = t./Ts;

nSampled = nan(size(t));
nSampled(1:10:end) = n(1:10:end);

zCont = @(t)(sin(pi*t/2)+cos(2*pi*t)+1);
zZOH  = @(n,Ts)(zCont(floor(n).*Ts));
zDisc = @(n,Ts)(zCont(n.*Ts));

figure;
plot(t,zCont(t),'b','DisplayName','Continuous'); hold on;
plot(t,zZOH(n,Ts),'r','DisplayName','ZOH'); 
stem(t,zDisc(nSampled,Ts),'k','DisplayName','Discrete'); 
legend('show');
```

This will give you the output as in the attached figure.[image]

You can try to play with ceil() or round() instead of floor() to get slightly different behavior. If you only need samples at integer values of n, that is something different altogether and is quite different to achieve for the general case (due to roundoff error in floats). However: for your case it will work by simply subsampling the index as is done in nSampled as the subsampling factor is 10. For a non-integer subsampling factor, this will not work properly.